# Monitor and Alert on Cloud Build errors with Stackdriver

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-logging

I'm looking for an option to monitor and create alerts whenever a Cloud Build fail - using Stackdriver.

Lots of people are solving this using Pub/Sub and Cloud Functions ([example](https://mehmandarov.com/slack-notifications-for-cloud-build/)) but I perfer to have all monitoring/alerting within Stackdriver. Stackdriver does have a Resource type named `Cloud Build` but there are no `Metrics` that makes any sense in terms of detecting a failed build. I'm guessing this is a missing feature?

[image]

Second option would be to analyze GCP logs (Log Viewer) and trigger an alert based on those events instead. The logs are there, but how can I utilize them inside Stackdriver?

[image]

Comment: If the logs contain the information you need, you can use Log-Based Metrics to trigger alerts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The log based metric suggested by @yuri-grinshteyn is the right way to achieve this. Go to [logging page](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer), on the right of the search field, click on the arrow and switch to advance filter.

Then paste this example

```
resource.type="build"
severity="ERROR"
```

This search only for `ERROR` level logs in the Cloud Build `resource`. Now, click on the upper left corner `Create Metric`. Simply name it and click on `Create metric`.

Now you are in the log based metric section. Click on the "3-vertical-align-dots" and select `Create alert on Metric`. Now there is a redirection to Stackdriver for creating an alert. Set `none` aggregator, the threshold that you want (if you want to be alerted on each fail, select 1). Save and, select your notification method and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Very helpful. As a follow up question, can you describe what the best way is to apply configure, deploy and update these custom Log-Based Metrics, Stackdriver Policies etc. across multiple GCP project? I have multiple GCP projects (one per client) and I'd like to ensure they each have the same monitoring/logging capabilities.